# TikZ grid out of sync with page boundaries

Tags: tikz-pgf, page, bounding-box

The following code

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[paperheight=297mm,paperwidth=210mm,margin=0mm,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw[help lines] (current page.south west) grid (current page.north east);
  \draw[help lines] (current page.south west) -- (current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

generates a grid which seems to be out of sync with the borders of the page, even thought the two points seems to be correct, based on the `--` diagonal path, as you can see below?

[From the documentation](https://tikz.dev/tikz-paths#sec-14.8) I would expect the grid to start and finish precisely on those 2 points.

---

Apparently, I've been not clear enough in the question. I am not puzzled by not being able to fill the whole page with an whole number of squares. I am puzzled as to why the squares don't start exactly from where I start the grid (then at the other 3 corners I can have less than a square along one, the other, or both directions)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `grid` operation of TikZ is based on the lower pgf layer with command `\pgfpathgrid`.
Its documentation [102.8 The Grid Path Operation](https://tikz.dev/base-paths#autosec-7988) explains the construction of the grid in more detail.

> `\pgfpathgrid[⟨options⟩]{⟨first corner⟩}{⟨second corner⟩}`
>
> Conceptually, the origin is part of the grid and the grid is clipped
> to the rectangle specified by the ⟨first corner⟩ and the ⟨second
> corner⟩. However, no clipping occurs (this command just adds parts to
> the current path) and the points where the lines enter and leave the
> “clipping area” are computed and used to add simple lines to the
> current path.

That means that the coordinates of the grid intersection points are multiples of the step settings. The default is 1 cm for both the x and y directions.

The sizes of the a4paper are 21 cm × 29.7 cm. The height is *not* a multiple of 1 cm. Therefore, it is not possible to have both the lower left and upper right corner as grid intersection points. Options:

- Change the step size for the vertical direction that the height becomes a multiple of the step size.
- Or decide which corner matches a grid intersection point.

The other issue is that you do not know *where* the origin of the node `(current page)` is. But this can be ensured with a transformation. The following code puts the origin (marked with a large red dot) in the lower left corner of the page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[paperheight=297mm,paperwidth=210mm,margin=0mm,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw[thick, shift=(current page.south west)]
     (0, 0) grid ($(current page.north east) - (current page.south west)$);
  % Visualize origin for grid
  \fill[red] (current page.south west) circle[radius=10mm];
  % Diagonal
  \draw[very thick, blue] (current page.south west) -- (current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Page grid with blue diagonal line and red dot at the lower left corner]

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand why my original solution doesn't work. They key of your approach is to have `shift=(current page.south west)` as an option, and then start the `grid` at `(0,0)` (where it ends is unimportant as far as alignment is concerned). Why is that different from not having a `shift` and starting the grid at `(current page.south west)`?

Comment: I mean, it looks to me that via `shift=(current page.south west)` you're setting where the origin of the coordinate system should be, and then you start the `grid` from that origin by specifiying `(0, 0)` offset from it. Why should that be different from starting at `(current page.south west)` and not shifting?

Comment: @Enlico `(current page.south west)` is actually `(0.0pt,-835.04684pt)`. With 1 cm = 28.4524 pt we get -835.04684pt = -29.3489 cm. It can be easily seen that the latter is not a multiple of 1 cm. The next visible horizontal grid line starts at -29 cm, leaving a "margin" of 0.3489 cm. By setting the origin of the grid explicitly with the trick in this answer, you can control the offset of the grid.

Answer (score 5):

Grid boxes are 1cm by default. So your grid can't start and end on those points. Also, the grid has intersections at integer values even when the coordinates aren't integers. Consider the following example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[blue](0,0)grid(7,5);
\draw[red, thick](.5,.5)grid(6.5,4.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've been not clear enough in the question, apparently. I was not puzzled by not being able to fill the whole page with an whole number of squares. I was puzzled as to why the squares don't start exactly from where I start the grid (then at the other 3 corners I can have less than a square along one, the other, or both directions).

Comment: +1. I had misunderstood the code.

Comment: Well, misunderstood the behavior actually.